# How to format file output into specific number of data columns?

Tags: python, file

I'm just asking a quick question on how to format how numbers are presented in a text file with however many columns I want.

ie.)

```
     1 3 4
     2 6 10
     3 18 6
```

As of right now my text file is just writing a new line for ever iteration and I'm having trouble figuring out how to get it to right a new line after 3 iterations of the calculation.

```
for Number in range(1, 10001):
    count = 0
    for i in range(2, (Number // 2 + 1)):
        if Number % i == 0:
            count = count + 1
            break

    if count == 0 and Number != 1:
        file.write(str(Number) + "\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could track the count of numbers written to file, and each multiple of three, write a newline.

```
output_count = 0
for Number in range(1, 10001):
    count = 0
    for i in range(2, (Number // 2 + 1)):
        if Number % i == 0:
            count = count + 1
            break

    if count == 0 and Number != 1:
        file.write(f'{Number} ')
        output_count += 1
        if output_count % 3 == 0:
            file.write("\n")
```

#### Code Refactor

It is recommended to refactor the code into functions that tackle pieces of the problem, such as calculating primes versus input/output. For example, in Python 3, you could write the following:

```
from typing import List


def generate_primes(maximum: int) -> List[int]:
    primes = []
    for n in range(1, maximum):
        count = 0
        for i in range(2, (n // 2 + 1)):
            if n % i == 0:
                count = count + 1
                break

        if count == 0 and n != 1:
            primes.append(n)
    return primes


def write_to_file(filename: str, data: List[int], columns: int) -> None:
    with open(filename, 'w') as file:
        output_count = 0
        for n in data:
            output_count += 1
            if output_count % columns == 0:
                file.write(f"{n}\n")
            else:
                file.write(f"{n} ")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    data = generate_primes(10001)
    write_to_file("primes.txt", data, columns=3)
```

#### Output

```
2 3 5 
7 11 13 
17 19 23 
29 31 37 
41 43 47 
53 59 61 
67 71 73 
79 83 89 
...
```